# How can I create Cloudtrail trail to log events of only a specific user/resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

How can we monitor API usage **only a specific user** in Amazon-Web-Services.
I tried creating Cloudtrail trail but it logs events of all users' all activity to the s3 bucket I configured to log it to.
I want only events (all activity) for a **particular** IAM User / Resource (using arn) to log to a S3 bucket

Answer (score 2):

CloudTrail logs everything. You’ll have to use some other tool to filter what you need and dig deep into the logs. Some of the tools are:

- [AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-logs-insights-fast-interactive-log-analytics/)
- [ElasticSearch / Kibana](https://hub.packtpub.com/cloudtrail-logs-amazon-elasticsearch/)
- GreyLog
- Splunk / SumoLogic / ...

There are many log parsing tools around to choose from.

Hope that helps :)